# Symbol resolution with jextract/clang

Tags: c++, c, clang, jextract

I'm trying to use a cpp library in java and for that I use [jextract](https://github.com/openjdk/jextract?tab=readme-ov-file).

My `.h` looked like this :

```cpp
int get_Unique_PrimaryKey_interface ();
```

While checking the `.so` with `nm -C` the symbol was present with the name `get_Unique_PrimaryKey_interface()`.
While running java I had the following error

```bash
 symbol lookup error: XXXXX.so: undefined symbol: get_Unique_PrimaryKey_interface
```

After some time I manage to fix that by changing my `.h` to the following :

```cpp
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" int get_Unique_PrimaryKey_interface ();
#else
extern int get_Unique_PrimaryKey_interface ();
#endif
```

The symbol is the `.so` now is `get_Unique_PrimaryKey_interface` and the java does call the C function.

The problem goes further when I try to call function from other library that I cannot change and do not use the `extern` keyword.
Jextract is always looking for the symbol as generated with `extern` but the libraries contains the symbols generated without it.

I'm trying to look for a clang flag to pass to jextract so it will look for both symbols. Does anyone know if there is a way to do that ?